# How to return array at end of loop (Newbie question)

Tags: javascript, loops

The following code (which I've simplified for clarity) loops through and returns the cardsToInsert before each part of the loop finishes, so the array doesn't get built properly.

The loops build the array correctly, but the result got returned near the beginning, not after it was built.

How do I get it to finish all the loops before returning the array?

```
async function loopCards(cardsToGet) {
  for (let cardToGet of cardsToGet) {
    getDataFunctionWhichReturnsAPromise()
       .then(async (card) => {
          writeCard = await buildingCard(card)
    cardsToInsert.push(writeCard)
  }
  return cardsToInsert
}
```

thanks

**Full Code Added as Requested**

// wixData.get() returns a promise

```
async function loopCards(cardsToGet) {
    let writeCard
    let buildCard
        for (let index = 0; index < cardsToGet.length; index++) {
            const cardToGet = cardsToGet[index].card
            buildCard =  wixData.get("Card", cardToGet)
                .then(async (card) => {
                    writeCard = await buildingCard(card)
                    cardsToInsert.push(writeCard)
                    }
                )
                .catch((err) => {
                    let errorMsg = err;
                    console.log("getcard error: " + errorMsg);
                    return errorMsg
                }); 
        }
        return cardsToInsert
}
```

Comment: Can you share your full code?

Comment: shared @zb22 thanks

Comment: Potentially relevant: [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: thanks @DBS how would I use this with the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a detailed explaination

1. loops are synchronous.
2. Promises are asynchronous.

To get the data from promises you need to wait for it to finish using callback,async-await or promise.

In your code, you are putting `.then` to access the result of wixData but the whole `wixData.get("Card", cardToGet).then(async (card) => {})` is an async function for `loopCards(cardsToGet)` and because of this your loop finishes and the result array is empty.

Solution -
Just wait for `wixData.get("Card", cardToGet)` to finish and then do the manipulations. Here is a solution using async await.

```
async function loopCards(cardsToGet) {

  let cardsToInsert = [];

  for (let index = 0; index < cardsToGet.length; index++) {
      const cardToGet = cardsToGet[index].card
      let card = await wixData.get("Card", cardToGet)
      let writeCard = await buildingCard(card)
      cardsToInsert.push(writeCard) 
  }

     return cardsToInsert
  }
```

In the above code I wait for the `wixData.get("Card", cardToGet)` to finish and store the result in get card. This should fix your problem.

but this code by performance is not optimal as you are waiting for each network call. what you can do is execute all the Promises at once using Promise.all

Here is the code for that with error handling -

```
async function loopCards(cardsToGet){

  try {

    return await Promise.all( cardsToGet.map( cardToGet => buildCard( cardToGet.card )));

  }
  catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
  }
}

async function buildCard(cardToGet){

  try {
    let card = await wixData.get("Card", cardToGet);
    let writeCard = await buildingCard(card);
    return writeCard;
 }
 catch (error) {
  console.log("getcard error: " + error);
  return error;
}
```

}

*The above code might have some erros since I haven't tested it but I hope you get the approach.*

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap loop with in promise .then or also you are using async its mean a very first item of array will be print and then it will await

```
getDataFunctionWhichReturnsAPromise()
       .then(async (card) => {
  for (let cardToGet of cardsToGet) {
          writeCard = await buildingCard(card)
    cardsToInsert.push(writeCard)}
  }
```

Comment: thanks @arsian, but the getDataFucntion needs to be inside the loop as it is needed to build the array

Comment: will you please remove async from .then method and then run code .. what happen

Comment: if I remove the async from the .them method I can't use await because it is no longer an async function

Comment: actually async gets 1st item of array and then it will out from main queee and thats why i think your loop returning only one item and promise also async dear

Comment: thanks, it's looping all the way through, and setting off a load of asyncronous functions I think. The loop itself I think completes very quickly, but those async functions are still running, and the correct array does get built in the end, I need it to return once the array is completed. To get it working I am writing the data from inside the loop once the array is the correct length. It works, but it's not elegant, and is probably causing some issues that I'm not aware off.

Comment: ok then wrap return in condition either if loop length-1 && return carttoinsert

Comment: that doesn't work because I have the same issue, the loop completes early, and it checks the condition, which isn't true so it doesn't return, but the function completes (even though the inside of the loop is still running), so the function returns anyway with an empty result.